# MySQL table name with accent. Invalid utf8 character string when updating via PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8, names

I'm in a situation where I need to update some rows in a table named "matrículas'. The query looks something like this:

```
UPDATE `matrículas` SET...
```

When I run this query in my SQL program (HeidiSQL) directly, it executes without problems. When I do it in PHP via a PDO object, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1300 Invalid utf8 character string: 'matr\xEDculas'
```

My PDO object is set up like this:

```
$db= new PDO(
    'mysql:host='.$credentials['host'].';dbname='.$credentials['dbname'].';charset=utf8',
    $credentials['user'],
    $credentials['password'],
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

The actual update is done by taking the above query and doing this:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($params);
```

Both the table and the database were created using the `utf8_general_ci` collation.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? btw, I'm currently testing in Windows in case that has anything to do with it...

Comment: Do you have any errors when you initialize the database connection?  Also have a try catch

Comment: Minor note: the charset should go in the DSN.

Comment: @Akintunde nope, no errors. and I actually caught that error above in a try/catch

Comment: @tereško - should go in the DSN? I just followed the example on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php (example 3)

Comment: did you check MySQL doc about [Identifiers converted to Unicode internally](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) to see what it says about `U+ED` ? don't know if it will help, might be worth reading...

Comment: Examine your PHP script with a hex editor.  Is the table name stored in the script as `matr\xEDculas` or `matr\xC3\xADculas` (with `\xNN` representing the hex value of one byte)? Code point 237 (`í`) in utf-8 is a 2-byte character `0xC3` `0xAD`, while `0xED` is the [Latin1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding.  The encoding is definitely the problem, but who fixes it, and where it's broken.... is where things are fuzzy to me.

Comment: @Chris try reading this tutorial: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, yep, didn't think to check the encoding of the php script. It was in `ISO-8859-1` instead of `UTF-8`. Changing that solved the problem. Blessed default encodings in Windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8 character string: 'matr\xEDculas'
```

The `\xNN` notation gives the hex encoded value for the invalid byte(s) in the character string.

Unicode code point 237 (í), when encoded in utf-8, is a 2-byte character that is encoded as `0xC3` `0xAD`... but the error shows `0xED`, which happens to be the [ISO/IEC-8859-1 (Latin1)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding for the character `í`.

Since the error is related to a column name being passed from the script rather than external data, that suggested what turned out to be the issue -- that the PHP script, itself, had the column name encoded incorrectly, since the character set in which the script had been saved was ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8.

Comment: tl;dr - Had to encode my PHP script to UTF-8. Windows saved it in ISO-8859-1 by default

Answer (score 0):

```
`matrículas`
```

this is cp866-gp2312 encoding

please change it to utf-8 like `matriculas`

i having the different encoding style

Comment: thing is, I have no control over the table name. I can't change it so that it doesn't have an accent...

Comment: `ED` is `í` only in cp1250, dec8, latin1, latin2, latin5, macroman.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use accented letters in table names, then they must be encoded in `UTF-8` *in the client*.

That is, it is not a `PDO` problem, but an encoding problem is your source editor/language/whatever.